# Using Array.from() in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am a little confused with Array.from() in JavaScript. I know/think that is turns array-like values into arrays, but why, if Array is an object, do we not have to use the 'new' keyword to instantiate it before we can use it?

Comment: `from` is not an instance method that fills an instantiated array, but rather a static method of the `Array` class itself.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has several collection types (HTMLCollection, NodeList, FileList, 'arguments', etc). The latter one being the variable containing all arguments passed to a function.

Imaging you have a function that requires data to be passed using an ordinary array - in that case Array.from(..) is super useful to convert any of the other collection types.

Answer (score 0):

`Array` is a function, functions are objects, objects have properties. `from` is just a property on that object. That fact that `Array` is a function and *can* be invoked with `new` is irrelevant.

Example:

```
function foo() {}

foo.bar = function() {
  console.log('hi');
}

foo.bar(); // hi
```

Presumably the primary reason for adding `from` as property to `Array` is to namespace it (instead of creating another global function).

Comment: Thanks. One quick thing though, and it may be a silly question - probably is - but if Array is a static function with methods on it, does that mean that Arrays I declare also have available the .from() method, because they are of type Array? Even though having that method would be useless on an array... Am I making any sense at all?

Comment: No. Arrays "inherit" all the methods defined on `Array.prototype`, not `Array`. Think about `Array.from` as a class method. It's defined on the class, not on its instances. Just like in my example above, if you did `var f = new foo();`, `f` wouldn't have the method `bar`. To learn more about functions and prototypes, have a look at http://felix-kling.de/jsbasics/#/10 .

Comment: And a secondary reason might be to allow subclassing :-)